# Como ejecutar una función al seleccionar una opción en DataList?

Tags: javascript, html, datalist

Como hacer para que al seleccionar una opción del tag **dataList**, se capturare el evento y este llame a una función **javaScript** para que el mismo llene un campo automáticamente luego luego de seleccionarlo.

Este es mi codigo.

```html
<form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // funcion que se ejecuta cada vez que se selecciona una opción

        function cambioOpciones()

        {

            document.getElementById('showId').value = document.getElementById('opciones').value;

        }
    </script>

    <datalist id='opciones' onchange='cambioOpciones();'>

        <option value=''>Selecciona una opción</option>

        <option value='1'>Opción 1</option>

        <option value='2'>Opción 2</option>

        <option value='3'>Opción 3</option>

    </datalist>

    <!-- input donde se mostrara el id de la opción -->

    <input type='text' id='showId' />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para usar el metodo **onchange()** debes escribir un tag **input** con su atributo **list**, indicándole el **id** del **datalist**, en ese mismo **input** debes escribir el método **onchange()**, para llamar a tu función.

Por otra parte, al parecer el tag **select** se adapta más a tu requerimiento, ya que en el  datalist muestra y obtiene su **value** de option, en cambio el select muestra un título y obtiene el value del mismo.

Aquí dos ejemplos con ambos tags.

```js
//Para el DataList
function cambioOpciones() {
  document.getElementById('showId').value = document.getElementById('valorOpciones').value;
}

//Para Select
function cambioOpcionesSelcet() {
  document.getElementById('showIdSelect').value = document.getElementById('opciones2').value;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
  //Aqui el script
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <form>
    Datalist:
    <input list="opciones" id="valorOpciones" name="opciones" placeholder="Selecciona una opción" onchange="cambioOpciones()">
    <datalist id="opciones">
      <option value='Opción 1' </option>
      <option value='Opción 2' </option>
      <option value='Opción 3' </option>
    </datalist>
    <input type='text' id='showId' />
</form>
<br><hr>

<form>
  Datalist:
  <select id="opciones2" name="opciones2" onchange="cambioOpcionesSelcet()">
    <option value="">Selecciona una opción
    <option value="1">Opción 1
    <option value="2">Opción 2
    <option value="3">Opción 3
   </select>
   <input type='text' id='showIdSelect' />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```